# Ubuntu 14.04 image preview never loads

Tags: debugging

After updating to 14.04 my image preview never shows up

[image: preview]

Is this common to update? Maybe it is related to my image viewer? Can I replace the default one or if its nautilus fault, what replacement would you suggest?

Comment: Try reconfiguring libthumbnailer0: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libthumbnailer0`

Comment: Should I restart after reconfiguring? Because without it it didnt do anything

Comment: log out then back in.

Comment: sadly it didn't do trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually face this when my computer is up for days and i don't clean my thumbnails folder.

what i do is i run this command to delete old previews and force generating new ones.

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/ -R
```

since i work with alot of images i added a line in my crontab to do so every 5 mins.

```
crontab -e
```

i add

```
*/5 * * * * rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/ -R
```

Comment: THanks it worked. and added `*/5 * * * * rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/ -R` line to conjobs